# Spring converter can't be diseable conditional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i use a Converter for OffsetDateTime for store they in SQLServer , but I dont want use it on H2, so i have try many think but it never work is always active....

My converter :

```
@Conditional(OffsetDateTimeConverterCondition.class)
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class OffsetDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<OffsetDateTime, String> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER_FROM_DB
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnn xxx");
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER_TO_DB
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn xxx");

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(OffsetDateTime attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.format(FORMATTER_TO_DB);
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : OffsetDateTime.parse(dbData, FORMATTER_FROM_DB);
    }

}
```

My class of condition :

```
public class OffsetDateTimeConverterCondition extends AnyNestedCondition {
    public OffsetDateTimeConverterCondition() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN);
    }
    

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "required.datasource.dbms", havingValue = "SQLSERVER")
    static class SQLSERVERCondition {
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "required.datasource.dbms", havingValue = "ORACLE")
    static class ORACLECondition {
    }
}
```

I have try to :

```
@Configuration
public class OffsetDateTimeConverterCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        
        return Arrays.asList(DBMS.SQLSERVER.name(), DBMS.ORACLE.name())
                     .contains(context.getEnvironment()
                                      .getProperty("required.datasource.dbms"));
    }
}
```

The setting is correctly set to SQLSERVER or H2, OffsetDateTimeConverterCondition return false when I am on H2 but it style active.

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work. The `AttributeConverter` isn't managed by Spring but by JPA (I suspect Hibernate). That doesn't know, nor care about the Spring conditional annotations.

Comment: So it can be active conditional (with a setting on profile) ? Or it's possible to register it only when it needed ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You are asking about your solution rather than the actual problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I need to store ***OffsetDateTime*** on `SQLServer` but is not suported so I need to converte they to ***String*** for store. That work perfectly , but now i need to be able to use `SQLServer` and `H2` ( choice is do in propertie) , but in `H2` you can directly store ***OffsetDateTime*** on a colum of ***TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE*** so i need to diseable converter